# Idiots Guide to compiling curl with ssh in Windows

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2008, curl

I am not a c developer, but I have been asked to to compile curl with ssh. I have downloaded the source for curl, libssh2 and openssl. I have managed to compile curl within VS2008, but I have no idea on to add the libssh2 and openssl.
  Any help would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow [the guide](http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/libs/libcurl) on PHP.net for windows. Or you can use this [really long guide](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/Using-libcurl-with-SSH-support-in-Visual-Studio-2008.pdf) for a more detailed walkthrough.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I managed to find a compiled version.
For anybody else who have the same problem, you can find it at 
http://www.gknw.net/mirror/curl/win32/ or http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2010-04/0071.html